# error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 30: found unknown escape character

Tags: kubernetes

When I want to run the following YAML file, I get the following error:
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 30: found unknown escape character

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
metadata:
  labels:
    run: $DEPLOYMENT_NAME
  name: $DEPLOYMENT_NAME
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: $TEMPLATE_LABEL
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: $TEMPLATE_LABEL
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wapp
        image: $IMAGE_WCE
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sed -i $a\-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true /opt/app/a.ini"]
```

I think it is the command caused the error.

```
sed -i $a\\-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true /opt/app/a.ini
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the problem is the `\-` in your sed command.
Just looking at the [yaml spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#style/flow/double-quoted), if you use double-quotes you have to escape the backslash, ie: `\\-`
but what about using single-quotes?

Comment: actually I have already tried adding an additional \ ,but still got the same error. let me try using single-quotes

Comment: changing to single quotes fixed it for me

Answer (score 4):

You have to add an additional `\` character to escape `\` in command. Also, replace `$` values in your manifest. Btw, the file has only 25 lines.

```
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sed -i $a\\-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true /opt/app/a.ini"]

$ cat deploy.yml 
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
metadata:
  labels:
    run: busybox
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: busybox
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: busybox
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wapp
        image: busybox
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sed -i $a\\-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true /opt/app/a.ini"]

$ kubectl apply -f deploy.yml 
deployment.apps/busybox created
```

Comment: actually I have already tried adding an additional \ ,but still got the same error.  I deleted some lines so you can ignore the line number

Comment: @Jeremy It's weird. Btw, I have updated the answer with the YAML I used.